# Fastest way to 30,000 kills with Arumat?

Tags: star-ocean-4

What is the fastest way to get the 30,000 kills Battle Trophy on Star Ocean 4: The Last Hope?

I'm thinking grinding something simple like bugs on Aeos but it's so boring, I'm wondering if something else would be better such as the scumbags and having fol+++ items to increase the fol return. Is there anything more sensible to grind while doing these kills?